# Primary key in text or convert md5 to integer?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, performance, postgresql

I'm building a database from different "open data" sources. I merge all these data together in a single table to get daily local events :

```
CREATE TABLE events ( uid bigint PRIMARY KEY, 
                      title text NOT NULL, 
                      description text, 
                      tel text, 
                      web  text, 
                      mail  text, 
                      more_info  text, 
                      place text, 
                      owner  integer, 
                      owner_name  text, 
                      category text, 
                      tags text[], 
                      date_start timestamp NOT NULL, 
                      date_end timestamp NOT NULL, 
                      approx smallint, 
                      latlong point NOT NULL
);
```

And for `uid`, I'm simply using the equivalent of `id` from the sources and using it directly.

I update the db everyday, got fetch the events of the day, check if the id is already here with `uid`.

I use a `TEMPORARY TABLE` to merge data while checking out duplicate (replace "columnsDefinition", "columnsName" and "values_n" with real content to keep it short here, you get the idea)

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE staging_my_table ("columnsDefinition");
INSERT INTO staging_my_table ("columnsName")  VALUES ("values_n")
INSERT INTO events ("columnsName") SELECT "columnsName" FROM staging_my_table staging WHERE (NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM events WHERE staging.uid = events.uid)) AND (date_end > CURRENT_DATE);
DISCARD TEMP;
COMMIT;
```

So far everything works perfectly.
But a new data source use text for id (ex. FMAMID031V507DMT), and I guess it is md5.

Should I alter my `uid` column from bigint to text ? Since I use it as a primary key (may have been a mistake from me), will it still work ? What about performance ?

Maybe I should find a way to transform these id to integer only, but I don't see how I could do it.

Maybe I need to generate my own `uid` from another column ?

What is the best solution ?

Thank you for your help and sorry if it doesn't belong here.

Comment: No, that's not a md5 hash. It's a text string, either random alphanumeric or structured in some way. To model this I'd probably switch to a surrogate primary key (`serial`) and then create `UNIQUE` constraints columns for `external_key_integer` and `external_key_text`, as well as a `CHECK` constraint that forces one of `external_key_integer` or `external_key_text` to be `NULL`.

Comment: For *actual* UUID values or  *actual* md5 hashes consider: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684